# python plotly subplots - set domain for table

Tags: python, dns, plotly

I'm trying to find out how i can set the domain for a table in a 2x2 subplot in plotly (V4.14.3).

I thought the "domain" option in `go.Table(domain=dict(x=[a,b],y=[c,d))` would be the right option but doesn't move while changing the values.

My goal is to have a fixed domain for the plots in the upper row and a dynamic table and legend in the lower one, so if i could variate the table position with a domain option it would be easy.

As you can see i set the domain in my code to `domain=dict(x=[0.0, 1.0],y=[0.2, 0.8])` which is different to the result you can see in the attached picture.

Thank you very much in advance

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Testdata
Test_DataSets = ['Set1','Set2','Set3']
Test_DataVals = [2,3,4]

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,5,7,9,6]


# Plots
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{"type": "scatter"},{"type": "scatter"}],
           [{"type": "table"},{"type": "scatter"}]
          ]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,y=y,
                         name= 'Testdata',
                         legendgroup = 'group'),1,1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,y=y,
                         name= 'Testdata',
                         legendgroup = 'group'),1,2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(domain=dict(x=[0.0, 1.0],y=[0.2, 0.8]),
             header=dict(
                 values=["DataSet", "Val"],
                 font=dict(size=10),
                 align="left"),
             cells=dict(
                 values=[Test_DataSets,Test_DataVals]
             )),
    row=2, col=1
)

fig.show()
```

[this the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh63C.png)
[thats how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2JQ6.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself...

the domain can be set with following code:

```
    fig.update_traces(domain_x=[0,0.45], domain_y=[0,0.45], selector=dict(type='table'))
```